# SearchView Android JCombobox behaviour

Tags: java, android, jcombobox, searchview

I have a question. I want to use a search view in an application in Android. All the tutorials I found deal with creating activities, setting all kind of metadata, etc, etc.

There is any way I could use a simple behavior like JCombobox in Swing ( give the view a list of possible values and have a listener when a choice is made) ?

Until now I found the following method than can be used to detect when a result is chosen.
((SearchView)findViewById(R.id.searchView)).**setOnQueryTextListener**(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {})

All the searchable information is given in a list of strings.
Thank you.

Comment: You can try `setSuggestionsAdapter()`, though I have not tried it.